# cs193p Concentration: Emoji display card flip delayed for cards that were already displayed, after new game is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I've successfully implemented a solution for the first assignment of Fall 2017 - Concentration.

Everything works fine, except that whenever you flip a card that was already displayed, after touching **new game**, there's a small lag/fade animation. This doesn't happen when you flip the card for the first time on the first game (see the video in the link below)

[Problematic behaviour example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyfo4sljuyomca5/delay.m4v?dl=0)

I thought this was a bug, but I checked other solutions and all of them have the same lag.

If anyone can give me a hint or knows why there is this lag, would really make me happy =)

Example solutions that have the same issue:

https://github.com/BestKora/Concentration-CS193P-Fall-2017

https://github.com/jamfly/cs193p-2017-fall-demo-and-solution

https://github.com/TiagoMaiaL/cs193p-assignments

My code for Concentration and ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    private lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: numberOfPairsOfCards)

    var numberOfPairsOfCards: Int {
        return (cardButtons.count + 1) / 2
    }

    private let emojiLibrary = ["☺️",
                                "⛓",
                                "",
                                "",
                                "⚽️⚾️⛳️",
                                "✊☝️"]

    private lazy var theme = emojiLibrary[emojiLibrary.count.arc4random]

    @IBAction func newGame(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Create new game struct, initialize everything Model
        game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: numberOfPairsOfCards)

        // Initialize everything view
        gameOverLabel.isHidden = true
        emoji.removeAll()
        theme = emojiLibrary[emojiLibrary.count.arc4random]
        updateViewFromModel(touchedCard: 0)
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var flipCountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet private var cardButtons: [UIButton]!

    @IBOutlet weak var gameOverLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction private func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let cardNumber = cardButtons.index(of: sender) {
            game.chooseCard(at: cardNumber)

            updateCardDisplay(index: cardNumber)
            updateViewFromModel(touchedCard: cardNumber)

            if game.gameOver {
                gameOverLabel.isHidden = false
            }
        } else {
            print("chosen card was not in cardButtons!")
        }
    }

    private func updateCardDisplay(index:Int)
    {
        let card = game.cards[index]
        let button = cardButtons[index]
        if card.isFaceUp {
            button.setTitle(getEmoji(for: card), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button.backgroundColor = card.isMatched ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

    private func updateViewFromModel(touchedCard:Int) {
        for index in cardButtons.indices {
            if index != touchedCard {
                let button = cardButtons[index]
                let card = game.cards[index]
                if !card.isFaceUp  {
                    button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
                    button.backgroundColor = card.isMatched ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                }
            }
        }

        scoreLabel.text = String("Score: \(game.score)")
        flipCountLabel.text = String("Flips: \(game.flipCount)")
    }

    private var emoji = [Card:String]()

    private func getEmoji(for card: Card) -> String {

        if emoji[card] == nil, theme.count > 0 {
            let randomStringIndex = theme.index(theme.startIndex, offsetBy: theme.count.arc4random)
            emoji[card] = String(theme.remove(at: randomStringIndex))
        }

        return emoji[card] ?? "?"
    }
}

extension Int {
    var arc4random: Int {
        if self > 0 {
            return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(abs(self))))
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}



struct Concentration
{
    private(set) var cards: [Card]

    private(set) var gameOver = false
    private(set) var flipCount = 0
    private(set) var score = 0
    private(set) var seenCards: Set<Card>

    private(set) var indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard: Int? {
        get {
            return cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp}).oneAndOnly
        }
        set {
            for index in cards.indices {
                cards[index].isFaceUp = (index == newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    private var numberOfPlayingCards: Int {
        get {
            return cards.count - cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isMatched}).count
        }
    }

    mutating func chooseCard(at index: Int) {
        assert(cards.indices.contains(index), "Concentration.chooseCard(at: \(index)): chosen index not in the cards")

        if indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard != index && !cards[index].isMatched {
            flipCount += 1
        }

        if !cards[index].isMatched {
            if let matchIndex = indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard, matchIndex != index {
                // check if cards match
                if cards[matchIndex] == cards[index] {
                    cards[matchIndex].isMatched = true
                    cards[index].isMatched = true
                    score += 2
                } else {
                    // mismatch of cards
                    if seenCards.contains(cards[index]) {
                        score -= 1
                    } else {
                        seenCards.insert(cards[index])
                    }
                    if seenCards.contains(cards[matchIndex]) {
                        score -= 1
                    } else {
                        seenCards.insert(cards[matchIndex])
                    }
                }

                if numberOfPlayingCards == 0 {
                    gameOver = true
                    cards[matchIndex].isFaceUp = false
                } else {
                    cards[index].isFaceUp = true
                }
            } else {
                indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard = index
            }
        }
    }

    init(numberOfPairsOfCards: Int) {
        assert(numberOfPairsOfCards > 0, "Concentration.init(\(numberOfPairsOfCards)): you must have at least one pair of cards")

        cards = [Card]()
        for _ in 1...numberOfPairsOfCards {
            let card = Card()
            cards += [card, card]
        }

        cards.shuffle()

        seenCards = Set<Card>()
    }
}

extension Collection {
    var oneAndOnly: Element? {
        return count ==  1 ? first : nil
    }
}
```

All code was based in the demo, so should be familiar to someone that did the cs193p course/assignments.

Thanks

Comment: That's too much code to expect your readers to go through and debug "by eye." You need to talk us through the relevant section that does the flip animation, and how the logic is different if the card has been flipped before. Also, if you really want help debugging it you should post the project to a public Github repo and add a link to your question so we can run it in the debugger and see if we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a video that shows the behaviour. If you need to build the entire project, I've added links to 2 projects that have the same issues so you can reproduce it from there with a debugger.